# Find and replace a new line character and a word in a file using shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file sample.txt whose contents are

```
line-1
Generic-text-1 line-2
Generic-text-2 line-3
line-2
Generic-text-1 line-2
Generic-text-2 line-3
```

I want to change the contents of the file to CSV to have the contents converted like below.

```
line-1,line-2,line-3
line-2,line-2,line-3
```

I am trying to use sed command but doesn't work with new line character.

```
sed -i 's/\nGeneric-text-1/,/g' sample.txt
sed -i 's/\nGeneric-text-2/,/g' sample.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `awk '$0=$NF' sample.txt | paste -d ',' - - -`?

Comment: You need more detail.  We can guess that the distinguishing characteristic between "line-1" and "Generic-text-1" is the presence of more than one string of non-white space in the line, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;$!N;s/\n\S+\s/,/;ta;P;D' file
```

Gather up lines, replacing the newline, the first field and its delimiter by a comma. When the match fails, print that first line, delete it and repeat.

A more detailed explanation:

- `-E` command line option extends regexps. In this case allows the shorthand `+` instead of `\+`.
- `:a` is a placeholder `a` that allows the execution of sed commands to resume at this point (used in conjunction with `ta` later on).
- `$!N` as long as the current line is not the last in the file `$!`, append the next line `N` to the current one in the pattern space. The pattern space is the buffer on which sed commands are executed.
- `s/\n\S+\s/,/` is the substitution command in which a `,` will be substituted for the match of a newline followed by one or more non white spaced characters followed by a white space character i.e. a word at the beginning of an appended line followed by a least a space.
- `ta` if the substitution was successful then jump the code execution to the place holder `a` i.e. go back 2 instructions.
- `P` at this point the last substitution failed and this prints up to and including the first newline in the pattern space.
- `D` this deletes up to and including the first newline in the pattern space. However, unlike the `d` command which restarts the sed cycle and reads the next line into the pattern space, this command only does so if the current pattern space is empty. If it contains values, it resumes at the first sed command in this case at the command `:a`.

Thus the sed program nibbles away at the file, creating and printing/deleting lines of its own making.

Or at a pinch:

```
sed -z 's/\n\S\+ /,/g' file
```

or:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n\S+ /,",")}1' RS= file
```

Comment: I will be more than grateful if you could explain me the options for the first solution you gave  :) 

sed -E ':a;$!N;s/\n\S+\s/,/;ta;P;D' file

Comment: Thanks a ton, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, you may do:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NF > 1 {
   printf "%s", OFS $NF
}
NF == 1 {
   if (NR>1)
      print ""
   printf "%s", $1
}
END {
   print ""
}' file
```

```
line-1,line-2,line-3
line-2,line-2,line-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
/^line/{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
  val=$1
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$NF
}
END{
  if(val){
     print val
  }
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, print only the last word of every line. Merge into one line using comma separator, all words between two occurences of the one-word lines.

```
awk 'NF==1 && NR!=1{print r; r=""} {r = (r? r "," $NF: $NF)} END {print r}' file
```

Output:

```
line-1,line-2,line-3
line-2,line-2,line-3
```